# Does the source branch get modified when merging two branches?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

Using TFS, let's say I have Branch1 and Branch2. There are some changes in Branch1 that I need in Branch2 (which was also modified). When merging the two branches, Branch1 will be the source branch and Branch2 the target branch.

Will Branch1 get modified somehow? Will the changes in Branch2 be effective on Branch1? I would like to avoid this.

Thanks a lot for your time and answers.

Comment: Just went for it like a crazy madman, hit the mouse clicks a few times and yes, I can confirm source branch does not get modified. Feel free to close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

If you are new to branching & merging in TFS, it's also easy to test. Go to one specific file which you know has changed in your branch2. Also Change the file in branch1 and try merging just that file. Then check in the pending changes, compare the specific file of branch1 with the two changest.

Something to watch for:

- You have to solve the conflicts for this file in the target (branch2)
- The file in source (branch1) will **be the same** version before merging.

Answer (score 0):

No, the source branch will not be modified.